# c# ChildForm.ShowDialog(ParentForm) does not work properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to place my child form on top of my parent form.
When switching between screens, when the child form is loading, it loses focus and gets trapped behind the parent form.

The code i am using is:

```
childForm.ShowDialog(this.ParentForm);
```

It seems that, when switching between applications on another screen, that the child form lose focus on the parent form.

*EDIT*
After using `childForm.ShowDialog(this)`, it still hides behind the parent form.

Comment: What is `this.ParentForm`? Are you sure it is not `null`?

Comment: Yes, you are wright, the parentForm is indeed null. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your snippet is totally inadequate to demonstrate the problem.  This is otherwise a common mishap when you hide a window before displaying the dialog and restore it afterwards.  For a brief moment, no window in your app can receive the focus when the dialog closes so Windows is forced to find another one.

Comment: Yes, i tried this. But still, after switching to another app, it hides behind the parent.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that `this.ParentForm` is `null` which means that you code is:

```
childForm.ShowDialog(null);
```

This explains the behaviour. Your child form is being created without an owner window. Without an owner window, `childForm` has no reason to appear on top of the main form, as you expect and intend.

I suspect that you want to make `this` be the owner of your window in which case you should change the code to:

```
childForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

or if `this` is the active form then it is sufficient to write:

```
childForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the owner of the form then you can is it as -

```
childForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of saying

```
childForm.ShowDialog(this.ParentForm);
```

just say

```
childForm.Show();
```

If you want to set the owner of the `childform` then set the `owner` property of form in design. See here for [Form.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx)